# Removing whitespace before a specified string MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database table called `phpbb_posts` - the column giving me difficulty is called `post_text` and is of `varchar(255)` type.

In the column `post text`, all of the 1200+ entries have some whitespace before the `</t>` tag which indicates the end of the entry. I want to remove this whitespace. Here's what it looks like:

[image: The column with whitespace]

I want to delete the whitespace before the last `</t>` in every field in the column, so that afterwards it looks like this:

```
<t>Battle Dart</t>
<t>War Dart</t>
<t>Francisca</t>
<t>Hurlbat</t>
etc...
```

How can I achieve this? I've looked at RTRIM, REPLACE and a few other functions but nothing seems to be working.

Not even sure if it is whitespace or if it is a new line... any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's new line, and you have just to use replace

```
UPDATE phpbb_posts SET post_text=REPLACE(post_text,"\n","");
```

If you have also some blanck, just redo a 2nd UPDATE with this new replace

Comment: Thanks for this - I added a 'WHERE' clause as well so that it didn't target posts before a certain time (because the new lines only appeared on posts after this time).

UPDATE phpbb_posts SET post_text=REPLACE(post_text,"\n","") WHERE post_time>=1623887666